# Elasticsearch catch-all field slowness after upgrade

Tags: elasticsearch

We upgraded a 2.4 cluster to 6.2 cluster using the reindex from remote approach. In 2.4, we were using the catch-all `_all` field to perform searches and were seeing response times under 500 ms for all our queries.

In 6.2, the `_all` field is no longer available for the new index, so we ended up creating a new text type field called `all` like `"all": {"type": "text"}` and set `copy_to` on all our other fields (about 2000 of them). But now, searches on this new catch-all field `all` are taking 2 to 10 times longer than the search on the 2.4 `_all` field. (We flushed the caches on both clusters before performing the queries.)

Both clusters are single data center, single node 8GB memory on the same AWS zone, hosted through elastic cloud. Both indices have the same number of documents (about 6M) and have about 150 Lucene segment files.

Any clues as to why?

**UPDATE:** Both indices return documents without the catch-all field i.e. they do not store the catch-all field.

Here is an example query and response:

```
$ curl --user "$user:$password" \
> -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
> -XGET "$es/$index/$mapping/_search?pretty" -d'
> {
>     "size": 1,
>     "query" : {
>         "match" : { "all": "sherlock" }
>     }
> }
> '
{
  "took" : 42,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 28133,
    "max_score" : 2.290815,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "sherlock",
      "_type" : "doc",
      "_id" : "513763",
      "_score" : 2.290815,
      "_source" : {
        "docid" : 513763,
        "age" : 115,
        "essay" : "Has Mr. Sherlock Holmes?",
        "name" : {
          "last" : "Pezzetti",
          "first" : "Lilli"
        },
        "ssn" : 834632279
      }
    } ]
  }
}
```

**UPDATE 2**: Another point I forgot to mention is that the 2.4 cluster is currently being used by a staging app, which sends a few queries to it every few minutes. Could this bring other factors like OS caching into play?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you store the `_all` field and returned it in your original setup? Do you return it now? If you didn't and now you do then that's a response overhead you are seeing and not a search overhead. Basically you should omit that field in your response (from you _source) if you don't need it (and any other field for that matter).

Check [_source filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-source-filtering.html) for more

Comment: No, the field is not stored in both the old index and the new index.

Comment: Is this field included in the `_source` field in the new index?

Comment: No, the response against both clusters do not return the catch-all field.

Comment: I added couple of updates to the qn, but is it possible that the 2.4 cluster has other factors helping it due to it being used by another client?

Comment: yeap this certainly would make a difference